# Poisson distribution; double check method?

Tags: self-study, distributions, poisson-distribution

Using Poisson Distribution

On average, 20cabs drive past your office every 30 minutes. What's the probability that 30 cabs will drive by in 1 hour?

To do this, I'm using the formula $$P(x) = \frac{(e^{-u}*u^x)}{x!} $$ where u is the mean number of successes.

I let u = 40 (since it's 20cabs/30 minutes) and let x=30, and got that P(x)=.0185

Is this the right approach?

Thank you

Comment: How do you interpret the event "30 cabs will drive by in 1 hour"? Do you mean *exactly* or *at least* 30?

Comment: Thank you for this question. I would interpret this as exactly P(x=30), but I didn't think about this! Would the formula be different for at least (P(x>=30))?

Comment: Yes, it would be different.  The interpretation is worth thinking about.  It seems to me that few people would ever be interested in the question whether *exactly* 30 cabs drove past their office, but they might be interested in whether *at least* 30 cabs did so.

Comment: Thank you! Wouldn't this take a while to solve, as would have to find the individual probabilities P(1)...P(30)? Or is there another way to do it, maybe using a different distribution

Comment: The tail probabilities are given by incomplete Gamma functions: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution.  All general-purpose software computing platforms will compute these values for you.

Comment: Sorry if these are basic questions, I'm just learning about these. If there's anything you can recommend to get more comfortable with distributions or building intuition I would be very grateful!:)